# Unable to save excel workbook on mac using xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm running the same Xlwings code with jupyter notebook on both MAC and Windows to save a new Excel workbook in a folder.

```
import xlwings as xw
import os

wb = xw.Book()
wb.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),r'pro/fi/g.xlsx'))
wb.close()
```

It runs on Windows fine but gives the following error on MAC;

```
CommandError: Command failed:
                OSERROR: -50
                MESSAGE: Parameter error.
                COMMAND: app (pid=71190). workbooks [ 'Book2'].save_workbook_as (filename='Macintosh HD: Users: mohit: Desktop: pro:fi:g.xlsx', overwrite=True, file_format=k.Excel_XML_file_format, timeout=-1, password=None)
```

Comment: I dont know about differences with MAC, however the 'raw' prefix is not necessary when using forward slashes on Windows or Linux. Shouldn't harm with Windows, but I don't know if the error message showing the path and filename as **pro:fi:g.xlsx** is an indication of the path separators being misinterpreted. There is also this SO post about the error with MACOS and Xlwings [Python xlwings: EventError: Command failed: Parameter error. (-50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987664/python-xlwings-eventerror-command-failed-parameter-error-50)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue and I noticed that was because I chose One Drive folder to save the file.

When I chose a folder outside One Drive the problem disappear.

Well, at the first instance the excel ask me to grant permission to save a file in the folder. But it saves without a problem on the subsequent safes.